# Moving Kitchen Worktop Cabinet Gap

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, cabinets, kitchen-counters

I've got an L shaped worktop that's attached to my kitchen wall with cabinets underneath. Pretty standard stuff.

There are two cutouts for white goods, where there's no cabinet but the worktop continues on top, the idea being you can slide a washing machine in where a cabinet would be.

Now, only one of them is plumbed (where I have my washing machine) and I'd like to get plumbing added to the other so that I can add a dishwasher. However, I had a plumber out today and they advised that it would likely be prohibitively expensive do to the length of the run, and the fact it would likely have to be cut into a stone wall to avoid the back of the cooker melting the pipe.

They then advised that I just move one of the cabinets from the other side of the kitchen to where I was planning on adding the plumbing to move the gap to be next to the existing plumbing.

Now, I have no idea how these units are generally constructed, is it usually a fairly simple operation to move them around like this? Are there any gotchas that I need to be aware of here?

I'm assuming you're going to need me to add some details to this to help you answer the question, but unfortunately, I don't know what you need to know, so I'll try to be as responsive as I can to comments.

---

Edit:

I want to move the cabinet marked X to where the tumble drier is and install a dishwasher in the newly created space (I'll replace the washing machine with a washer dryer). Excuse the mess...

[image: Kitchen Layout]

The inside of the cabinets:

[image: Inside of Cabinet]

Comment: Usually cabinets and counter tops are not connected together that well, so moving cabinets should be possible without destroying/ripping stuff apart.  If at the end of the counter top, will probably need to build a end wall for the top support.

Comment: Pictures of the overall layout of the cabinets, indicating which cabinet would be moved, as well as a closeup of the inside of the frames would be helpful. Usually, cabinet fronts are screwed together through the face frames to make all the individual cabinet units into one solid piece. It _could_ be just a straight forward "unscrew, rearrange, screw back together". If you have flat-pack IKEA style cabinets, it might be even easier. If they're custom built in, it might be impossible. Pics will help us determine.

Comment: @FreeMan - That sounds promising, do the pictures I've added help>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cabinets are "Full overlay"  without face frames. You have the door the drawer and a box.

Taking a single cabinet out can be a daunting task.
They are usually screwed to the wall at the upper rear and to the countertop.  If the counter is some type of stone. Then they can be "glued" . You will have to try to break that bond.

Often the cabinet boxes are screwed to each other to prevent shifting and eliminate an unsightly gap between the boxes.

Remove the door and drawer first. Look for any screws in the cabinet box and any in cabinets adjoining the one to be removed.  Remove all the screws. ( some in the sides of the box can be covered with a caulking to hide them and may be unnoticeable.

If there is a cover strip over the toe kick at the very bottom, that must be removed as well.

Once you have the box to a point it will move some, I have taken old screw on door pulls and attached one to each side of the inside of the box. This will give you something to hold on to to "wiggle" the box out.

Good Luck

Comment: Often (as I did with my IKEA office cabinets) the screws holding two cabinets together are hidden in one of the holes that would otherwise hold a shelf support or are covered by a door hinge. I don't see any screws at the top of the "cabinet" portion holding this to the wall - they could be behind the drawer. This looks to be a wood laminate counter top, good news is that it _might_ be screwed down, not glued. If it's glued, removing a cabinet is likely to destroy the cabinet, counter or both...

Comment: @FreeMan,  yeah, the counter looks like butcherblock or laminate.  Most likely not glued, but it depends on who installed it.  Most installs are done without any regard for removal.

Comment: Good advice. Don’t forget that the cost of a new cabinet is relatively low, so destroying the existing cabinet is a viable option.

Comment: Fair point, @AloysiusDefenestrate, though OP may need to factor in a new countertop, as well. Still cheaper, most likely, than running new plumbing.

Comment: @RMDman - It's laminate... This place is rented, they wouldn't get us something as nice as butcher block. I don't think destroying the cabinet or counter is a viable option, as finding an exact match to the cabinet would be nigh impossible. If I can't get it out non-destructively, I'm going to do without the dishwasher I think

Comment: @ScottishTapWater if it's rented, are you actually allowed to make the changes you're proposing?

Comment: @Huesmann - Probably not... but it's managed by a trust so as long as it looks fine when I'm done they won't notice and if they do they won't care